# A name for this statistical approximation?

Tags: statistics, inequality, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Heuristic calculations suggest the following approximation (see counter-example in comments) for random sets $\{x_i\}_{i\in[N]}$ and $\{c_{i,j}\}_{i\in[N]}$ for $j\in[C]$ (the larger $C$ the better the approximation)
$$
    \left(\sum_{i=1}^N 1\right)\sum_{j=1}^C \left(\sum_{i=1}^N c_{i,j}x_i\right)^2
    \approx \left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2\right) \sum_{j=1}^C \left(\sum_{i=1}^N c_{i,j}\right)^2
$$
I realize the similarity to Cauchy-Schwarz but I'm still stuck on why this seems to hold.
Is there a name for this relationship?
Any reasons it should or should not hold?

A statistical interpretation is that $\{x_i\}_{i\in[N]}$ is a data set with mean $0$ and variance $\left(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2\right)/N$.
We calculate the variance of the dot products of $\{x_i\}_{i\in[N]}$ with $C$ i.i.d. random sets $\{c_{i,j}\}_{i\in[N]}$ for $j\in[C]$.
We approximate this dot product variance by multiplying the variance of $\{x_i\}_{i\in[N]}$ with the variance across the $C$ sets $\{c_{i,j}\}_{i\in[N]}$ of the sum of values $\sum_{i=1}^N c_{i,j}$ in each $j\in[C]$ set.
That is,
$$
    \frac{\sum_{j=1}^C \left(\sum_{i=1}^N c_{i,j}x_i\right)^2}{C}
    \approx \left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i^2}{N}\right)\left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^C \left(\sum_{i=1}^N c_{i,j}\right)^2}{C}\right)
$$
Any name for this pattern in the statistical context?
Any reasons it should or should not hold?

Comment: Do you assume that $c_{i,j}\leq 1$?

Comment: If $c_{1,1} = x_1 = 1$ and all other values are zero then the inequality becomes $N \le 1$.

Comment: @Yanko No, just both are real sets

Comment: @MartinR So then it's more a statistical approximation (updated)